# No se guardan el Latitude y Longitude después del OnMarkerDragListener();

Tags: java, android, firebase

Alguien me podría decir por qué no se guardan el nuevo `Latitude` y `Longitude` después de hacer el `OnMarkerDragListener();`? He cambiado el código varias veces para intentar a arreglarlo, pero siguen sin guardarse.

La primera opción de guardar la ubicación que tiene el usuario es si está contento con la ubicación del `Search`, pues deja allí el marcador y ya está. Esto sí que se guarda.

La segunda opción que tiene, si no está contento, pues arrastra el marcador y lo deja en algún otro sitio del mapa. Ahora, el nuevo `Latitude` y `Longitude` deben de guardarse y no el `Latitude` y `Longitude` del `Search`.

Abajo tienen mi código.

**MapsActivityPublisher.java**

```
GoogleMap map;
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
    SearchView searchView;
    Location currentLocation;
    FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;
    Marker marker;
    Address address;
    LatLng latLng;

    String location;

    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 101;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps_publisher);

        searchView = findViewById(R.id.sv_location);
        mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.google_map);
        fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                location = searchView.getQuery().toString();
                List<Address> addressList = null;

                if (location != null || !location.equals("")) {
                    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(MapsActivityPublisher.this);
                    try {
                        addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(location, 1);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    if (addressList != null)
                        if (addressList.size() > 0) {
                            address = addressList.get(0);
                            latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());
                            if (marker == null) {
                                marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(location).draggable(true));
                            } else {
                                marker.remove();
                                latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());
                                marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(location).draggable(true));
                            }
                            dragMarker();
                            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 10));

                            final String postid = getIntent().getStringExtra("postid");
                            final Button buttonDone = findViewById(R.id.button_done);
                            buttonDone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts");
                                    reference.child(postid).child("latitude").setValue(address.getLatitude());
                                    reference.child(postid).child("longitude").setValue(address.getLongitude());

                                    startActivity(new Intent(MapsActivityPublisher.this, MainActivity.class));
                                    finish();
                                }
                            });
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(MapsActivityPublisher.this, "Modify search", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                }

                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                return false;
            }
        });

        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        CheckEnableGPS();
        fetchLastLocation();
    }

private void dragMarker() {
        map.setOnMarkerDragListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {
                Toast.makeText(MapsActivityPublisher.this, "Place marker where Event will take place", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker) {
                //Nothing
            }

            @Override
            public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {
                latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas guardando los datos Latitude y Longitude de *Address* que no se actualiza al desplazar el marcador, mediante las siguientes lineas:

```
@Override
public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {
latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());
}
```

En ves de eso debes guardar los datos del marcador

```
@Override
public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {
latLng = marker.getPosition();
}
```

Comment: Lo he hecho pero sigue dándome la ubicación Latitude y Longitude de la búsqueda... Creo que es porque en ```reference.child(postid).child("latitude").setValue(address.getLatitude());``` tengo ```address.getLatitude();``` Es cierto? Y cómo lo cambio para que me de la ubicación nueva?

Comment: Donde esperas que se guarde? En latLng o en Address, si esperas que se guarde en adress deberías incluir algo como  Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getBaseContext());
                try {
                    address=geocoder.getFromLocation(latLng.latitude,latLng.longitude,1).get(0);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "No se encontro una direccion para este marcador", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }     despues de hacer el latLng = marker.getPosition();

Comment: Vale tío, ya funciona, gracias. El ```latLng = marker.getPosition();``` es lo que necesitaba, crea un nodo nuevo que se denomina ```location``` y allí se guarda el ```latLng``` con la ubicación correcta. Gracias por todo!

Comment: Te puedo preguntar otra cosita? Cuando me lleva a la página del mapa donde eliges tú la ubicación del evento, se escribe en el buscador el nombre de la ciudad por ejemplo Roma, y SIEMPRE pasa que la primera vez que lo haces te echa del mapa y se vuelve a cargar el mapa y buscas otra vez la ciudad y sale bien... Es decir la ciudad se encuentra. Pero la primera vez que buscas siempre me echa de la página del mapa. Alguna idea el porqué me pasa esto?